# Single Photon Detection Using an FPGA

Tags: amplifier, fpga, photodiode, hardware

I am an undergraduate student working on a summer project involving single photon detection and coincidence counting. The main issue with the project is that the voltage threshold preset into the hardware of the FPGA is 3V to trigger the counter. However, the output voltage of the avalanche photodiode is only around 1.5 to 1.8 volts.

My colleagues and I want to design an amplifier that will amplify the signal from the APD to the FPGA so that accurate counts can be made. Several attempts were made at this in 2019 when students used several circuit designs involving TTL and ECL comparators, a BJT amplifier, Schmitt Trigger, and lastly a Non-inverting Op-Amp. Their attempts were unsuccessful due to the fact that the high speed and low amplitude of the signal from the APD. Additionally, these students found that the ICs that were purchased did not behave at their specified speeds. They underperformed. I have attached the components used by these students below. I would love some ideas on how to troubleshoot this that don't involve buying a new FPGA as this is not cost-effective. Are there any Op-Amps out there that have a high slew rate (over 4V per nanosecond) that can amplify pulses below 2V?

[image: components]

Upon request, I have added an image of the signal we would like to amplify. The pulse that we are interested in amplifying has a width of about 10-20 ns but the entire pulse (noise included) is around 314 ns. I just spoke to one of my colleagues and they mentioned needing a printed circuit board because yes, the white plastic breadboard used in lower-division labs just doesn't cut it here.

[image: wave pulse from APD]

Comment: What bandwidth do you require? You can always make this work by lowering the bandwidth, but usually you have some requirements that prevent you from going very low where the problem is easy.

Comment: Can you show an oscillogram of the output of the detection device during a single photon event? Also, specifications of the detection device like output impedance? Have you tried a fast comparator (LM7171 is ho-hum as far as fast part go, MAX9693 is pretty good) like Analog Devices ADCMP572? Perhaps feed the comparator in to a fast flip-flop and reset the FF with the FPGA to pulse stretch. As for the parts previously used not meeting specification, construction techniques for high speed circuits is critical.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with the pulse duration and the timing resolution you're trying to achieve.  Using a fast comparator is the correct way to go here, but first you need to choose the right chip, and then you need to use it correctly.  If you're considering using one of those white stick-a-wire-in breadboard let us know -- we'll explain why that simply doesn't work for high-speed signals.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with FPGA and everything to do with detecting a single photon

Comment: Are you hoping for single photon detection with an APD biased only to 1.8 V?  Or is that the expected impulse on the other side of some AC coupling?  We need to see your circuit and know more about your expectations.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. An edit to the original post including an image of the signal we would like to amplify has been made. This is my second day on this project so my apologies if I cannot answer all of your questions at the moment.

Comment: The comment "did not behave at their specified speeds" suggests either a lack of understanding in interpreting the specifications such as overdrive or unreliable sourcing. We can help with the former, but the latter is pretty much "DON'T do it", especially if you are in a learning mode.

Comment: This is a high speed analog or RF problem.  Not a digital/FPGA problem.

Comment: I'm working on the best answer I can at the moment, but if you could edit your question some _more_ -- what is the detector, and how is it connected.  You're talking of signals with a bandwidth in excess of 50 or 100MHz, so hopefully that detector is mounted on the same board as your comparator, or it's on the end of good coax and it's mounted with careful attention paid to impedance discontinuities (and if not -- that explains that horrid ringing).